# Load navigational property/related entity from a different source through httpClient

Tags: c#, foreign-keys, asp.net-core-webapi, entity-relationship, ef-core-2.2

In our company we are building an application for a client (as usual). We use Entity framework, .net Core 2.2 and we are creating a webapi that is consumed through a javascript framework as a front. My main concern is how we loaded the entities before and after our last feedback with the client. 
Our main implementation for loading an department before the last feedback from the context was:

```
var department= await _dbcontext.Departments.Where(x=>x.Department, == Id)
                 .Include(x=>x.Employees)
                 .Include(x=>x.Salaries).ToListAsync();
```

Pretty straighforward and solid, respects entity framework as we know it.

The client then informed us that the **employess** and **salaries** will exist in different databases that we will not know and that the dependencies should be fetched through http client and then somehow get loaded as navigation properties in the current model of the dbcontext.
They explained that we had to break the current api into three apis independent of each other.
The foreign keys will exist, such as employeeId-depId and employeeId-salaryId but the navigation properties will be from elsewhere.

Assuming I call a list of employees through httpClient like this,

```
private List<Employee> CallHttpClient(int depId)
        {
            List<Employee> Results = new List<Employee>();
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {

                client.BaseAddress = new Uri($"somepath/api/Employees/GetEmployeesByDept/{Id}");

                var response =
                    client.GetAsync();

                response.Wait();
                var result = response.Result;

                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Employee>>();
                    readTask.Wait();

                    Results = readTask.Result;
                }


            }
            return Results;
        }
```

and call it like this:

```
var department= await _dbcontext.Departments.Where(x=>x.Department, == Id).FirstOrDefault();
List<Employees> employees = CallHttpClient(department.Id);
```

How will I load the employees as a navigational property in the departments and work with it? Can we even work with linq joins properly like this if it is needed?

Comment: Well... the terminology of *navigational properties* goes out the window in this cause, they are just regular *properties*, for which you will have to fetch and poke them in on the fly. There are ways to get trickier, but it would only make a bad problem worse in my opinion

Comment: I know that very well TheGeneral... That is why I posted a question if anyone had a way of showing me an implementation of how to "poke them in on the fly"... btw this is a nice catchphrase I want to borrow it...

Comment: Except if the related entity data is mapped to linked tables in the same database as the primary entity data, they cannot be mapped as *navigation* properties. Hence the class holding them should not be an entity, but ViewModel/DTO and populated manually from different sources.

Comment: As a matter of a fact we will use dto's for this at the end of the day. But i was wondering is this a common practice when you "break" the context?? Is it considered good/bad??